# Decomposition of a sum of matrix products with itself

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given tall matrix $B \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times r}$, where $n \gg r$, and vector $c \in \mathbf{R}^n$, let

$$ A A^T := B B^T + c c^T $$

I would like to get any possible matrix $A$ efficiently. If possible, smaller than a square matrix. Is there a solution? Would it help if $BB^T$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what you asked, but I have the matrix $B$ and the vector $c$ as input, and I'd like to get any possible $A$ as output.

Comment: How about $A = \begin{bmatrix} B & c \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo: it's elementary, my dear Watson... But I wasn't seeing it... Of course it will remain a "tall" matrix...

Comment: I think that's the solution. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} B & c \end{bmatrix}$$